# Condicionar navbar de acuerdo al rol

Tags: nodejs, express, passport, navbar, handlebars

He creado ingreso con login y passport

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email',  
}, async (email, password, done) => {
  // Comprobar si existe el Email
  const user = await User.findOne({email: email});  
  if (!user) {
    return done(null, false, { message: 'No se ha encontrado Usuario' });
  } else {
    // Si el password es correcto   
    const match = await user.matchPassword(password);
    if(match) {
      **console.log(user.rol)**
      return done(null, user);      
    } else {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'Clave Incorrecta.' });
    }
  }
}));
```

el controlador es

```
usersCtrl.signin = passport.authenticate("local", {
successRedirect: "/pedidos/add",
failureRedirect: "/users/signin",
failureFlash: true
```

});

la ruta es

```
router.post("/users/signin", signin);
```

Y logro que con un console.log desde passport me muestre si es Administrador o Cliente, en este caso:

```
Servidor en Puerto 4000
DB está conectado
***Administrador***
```

Qusiera que de acuerdo a esto poder que un navbar o menu me oculte algunos "ul" dependiendo si es administrador o cliente.....he intentado y no he podido, yo creo porque soy nuevo en js o algo tonto

Comment: Hola. Generalmente mando la estructura del menú desde el backend.Esto lo hago en base a los roles del usuario que están almacenados en mi BD.

Comment: Gracias por responder, perdoname la ignorancia me puedes con un ejemplo mostrar como lo haces

Answer (score 0):

Una aproximación podría ser:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email',  
}, async (email, password, done) => {
  // Comprobar si existe el Email
  const user = await User.findOne({email: email});  
  if (!user) {
    return done(null, false, { message: 'No se ha encontrado Usuario' });
  } else {
    // Si el password es correcto   
    const match = await user.matchPassword(password);
    if(match) {
      **console.log(user.rol)**

      //No se muy bien como funciona esto pero me imagino que retornas un
      // json después de esto. 

      const menus = comprobarMenus(user)
      return done(null, user, menus);      
    } else {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'Clave Incorrecta.' });
    }
  }
}));
```

`comprobarMenus(user)` seria algo asi:

> Esta codigo esta echo sobre la marcha y puede que no funcione

```
function comprobarMenus(user){


   const menus = [

        {
          titulo: 'Menu de pedidos',
          permiso: 'menu:pedido',
          submenus: [
              titulo: 'Ver pedidos',
              permiso: 'menu:pedido:verPedidos',
              cosasExtras: ...
          ]    
      },
      {//...Mas menus}
   ]


   return menus.filter(m=>{
       //Quitamos los submenus que no queremos
       m.subMenus = m.subMenus.filter(sub=> user.permisos.includes(sub.permiso))

       //Si el usuario no tiene permiso no agregamos el menu
       // Suponiendo que tu objeto usuario tenga la propiedad permisos. 
       return user.permisos.includes(m.permiso)
   })

}
```

Comment: Trato de hacer el menu pero no entiendo como quedaria...si me puedes ayudar..muchas gracias

Comment: No se en que más te puedo ayudar. Que haz logrado?

Comment: Es un navbar de boostrap el cual tiene etiquetas "ul" y "li" de HTML, no logro ubicar tu codigo en esta navegacion para que NO se muestren algunas etiquetas "li", que serian solo accesibles si eres administrador o sea que no se vean en usuarios generales, Lo que ya tengo es que si se loguea se ocultan algunas "li" pero no discrimina si es administrador o no. En el codigo que tu ves, lo que hace passport es buscar por usuario(user) el email y si existe y coincide con el password retorna todos los datos de usuario incluyendo si es administrador o no, 
estoy usando handlebars(plantilla HTML)

Comment: Te recomiendo que actualices tu pregunta con esa información. Asi en el comentario no entiendo el problema.